Integrate Lighthouse Report to jenkins
I am trying to integrate https://plugins.jenkins.io/lighthouse-report/ plugin.
I have installed the plugin in jenkins but when i run this command:
node {
   sh 'npx lighthouse-ci http://localhost:8080/ --jsonReport --report=.'
    lighthouseReport file: './report.json', name: 'My Report'
}

I get the ERROR:
npx: installed 246 in 8.925s
Unexpected token =

I was expecting it to generate a lighthouse report, instead i am getting this error.
Unexpected token =

Can someone please help me with this.

The output is rather sparse, can you add --verbose to the npx lighthouse-ci call?

Added the same, but still shows the same error @iterokun

I was kinda hoping for more output. Can you add set -x; right before the npx lighthouse-ci call?
